# Regular Expression Find all LF characters not CRLF hexadecimal

Tags: regex

I am viewing a CSV file which has LF characters in the middle of a field and CRLF character to actually denote a new line. I am viewing the file in hexadecimal in Sublime Text 3 and I want to do a simple find and replace where I search for LF characters but NOT CRLF and replace it with a space.

I've gotten as far as to search for LF but NOT CRLF, I could use the regular expression

`[^0d]0a`. Problem with this is that it doesn't capture the case where you could have XX0d 0aXX and I don't know how to capture this with regular expressions. I would then want to replace this with '20' which is space in hexadecimal.

Comment: `[^0d]` doesn't do what you think. It matches any single character that isn't `0` or `d`, it doesn't match a sequence.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now, I'm at something like this: `^((?!0d).)0a`, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Barmar. You're right. I read it incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: `(?!0d)` is a lookahead, you want a lookbehind.

Answer (score 8):

Use a negative lookbehind that matches `0d` with optional whitespace.

```
(?<!0d\s*)0a
```

However, some regexp engines won't allow quantifiers in lookbehinds. So you may need to put the whitespace check after the lookbehind, and then capture it to use it in the replacement.

```
(?<!0d)(\s*)0a replace with ${1}20
```

It would probably be easier if you did this in text mode instead of hex. Replace

```
(?<!\r)\n
```

with space.

Comment: the 3rd one -`(?<!\r)\n`- worked in notepad++ for me.